# Official Lint Way

Tags: chisel

In order to lint code, I use the following command;

```
sbt 'test:runMain dir.HogeMain'
```

where `dir` is directory from root having **sbt** file, and `HogeMain` is main module name or project name.
This way, of course, enters into testing with test code, unnecessary for the lint work. Does anyone know **official lint command**?

Comment: The command you’ve shown is only to invoke a Scala main function (in the “test” project), the fact that it’s running simulations is due to the actual code in the main function. Can you show the code in `dir.HogeMain`?